# onclick works just while the page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery code runs just while the page is loading, after the page is loaded completely it does not work, what to do???

```js
$('.slider').click(function() {
  console.log('hassan');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <button style="background-color:transparent" id="left-arrow" class="glyphicon 
 glyphicon-menu-left"></button>

</div>
```

Comment: The snippet above works so you need to add more evidences that will prove your code do not work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess earlier you were calling a function,like this,

```
$('.slider').click(someFunction());
```

instead of doing this,

```
$('.slider').click(someFunction);
```

while registering function for click event.
The code snippet you have attached works fine.

Answer (score 0):

remove the class **slider** from your div and put it in your button class

```
 <div class="">
    <button style="background-color:transparent" id="left-arrow" class="glyphicon 
     glyphicon-menu-left slider"></button>
 </div>
```